# Fastest way to put files in a network folder / saveas or filecopy?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to save Excel files in both the local drive and in the network folder. Currently I am doing it with SaveAs (local) and another SaveAs (network), is it faster to do a SaveAs then FileCopy?

Code below:

```
Sub SaveAs()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws_console As Worksheet
    Dim long_col_number As Long
    Dim long_sheets_count As Long
    Dim arr_sheet_names As Variant
    Dim str_password As String
    Dim str_datetoday As String
    Dim str_datetoday_path As String
    Dim str_datetoday_network_path As String

    str_datetoday = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    str_datetoday_path = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Report\" & str_datetoday
    str_datetoday_network_path = "\\servername\data\reports\US Reports Daily\" & str_datetoday

    If Dir(str_datetoday_path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir (str_datetoday_path)
        MsgBox "Making directory"
    End If

    If Dir(str_datetoday_network_path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir (str_datetoday_network_path)
    End If

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.CodeName = "AILD_01_Console" Then
            Set ws_console = ws
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws

    long_col_number = 0

    For long_col_number = 1 To 8

        long_sheets_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws_console.Range(Cells(16, long_col_number), Cells(24, long_col_number)))

        arr_sheet_names = ws_console.Range(Cells(16, long_col_number), Cells(15 + long_sheets_count, long_col_number))
        arr_sheet_names = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr_sheet_names)

        Worksheets(arr_sheet_names).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
            Filename:=str_datetoday_path & "\" & ws_console.Cells(15, long_col_number) & " - " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd"), _
            FileFormat:=51

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
            Filename:=str_datetoday_network_path & "\" & ws_console.Cells(15, long_col_number), _
            FileFormat:=51

        ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    Next long_col_number

    ws_console.Activate

End Sub
```

Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: Currently, it is taking me 28 minutes to finish the whole copying process.

Comment: Isn't this something that you could test yourself to figure out faster than you could write and post your question here?

Comment: I'm 90% sure it'll be faster to save them all to one location one by one and then copy the files across in one go, rather than two lots of SaveAs.

Comment: @KenWhite that's a fair point, was always trigger happy to post questions, anyway I am in a hurry to get quick insights from experts. Why not ask and test?

Comment: No problem. It just seems that a "SaveAs" operation will come with a lot of extra events, whereas copying files is just... copying files!

Comment: Part of the way this site works is for you to try *extensively* to solve the problem yourself *before* posting here. Note that it's **before** asking for help here. Asking questions about things you can easily figure out yourself both wastes your time and ours, because we could be spending that time helping others who really need the hellp rather than those who just can't be bothered to make an effort.

Comment: @KenWhite Okay :)